# Handling dynamically-typed variables in LLVM

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-clang

I've recently written a dynamically-typed interpreted programming language as a learning exercise. I'm now looking to enable the generation of LLVM bitcode via LLVM's C binding, but I'm struggling when it comes to the handling of 'typeless' variables. Since IR is strongly-typed, my initial thought was to represent values in the IR as structs, like so (where `type` represents either a numeric, bool or string value):

```
typedef struct
{
    ValueType type;
    double double_value;
    bool bool_value;
    char *string_value;
} Value;
```

To help with the manipulation of `Value` structs I would link the generated bitcode with a static library that my LLVM IR could call into. The static library would handle things like string concatenation and the execution of mathematical operators, returning the resulting `Value`, like so:

```
Value apply_op(char *op, Value *lhs, Value *rhs);
```

But is this the best approach? As stated above, this is largely a learning exercise, so I wanted to be sure that I wasn't overly complicating things, or fundamentally misunderstanding a core piece of LLVM functionality.

Comment: While I think the question is too broad, I wonder if you really mean weakly typed or dynamically typed. Note that these are very different subjects. For the latter an OOP approach might be best; how else could you represent acompile-time defined type in your `struct`?

Comment: That is how dynamically typed values are usually stored, but I think bytecode is normally dynamically typed and everything is handled in the interpreter.  The Python and Perl source may be worth looking at.  JVM Hotspot langauges might be a good example of statically typed bytecode being used for a dynamic language.

Comment: @Olaf I did indeed mean dynamically typed. Regarding your question about compile-time defined types, provided I'm understanding the question, I'd generate the LLVM IR to allocate an instance of the `Value` struct and set it's type to match the right-hand constant (i.e: `a = 1` would generate a `Value` struct with a numeric type).

Comment: @ndg: My point was more what if the right-hand type was a user-defined tpye, i.e. a compound type? I will not discuss further, as this is against site-rules, but you might have a look at other dynamically typed languages, like Python, Ruby, or - AFAIK - Lua. Note that at least Python and Ruby are very well **strongly** typed (not sure about Lua, though).

Comment: This is how I implemented a dynamically typed language at work. For a few simple cases (int, float, date, ...) the creation of values were done by IR directly (where the code generator used C++ classes to wrap a llvm::Value* and had functions like setInt, setFloat, ...). For more complex cases (tuples, strings..) the IR calls runtime supoort routines like in your code.

Comment: You can try to compile your support routines to llvm ir using clang, and link it to your module. llvm could then inline small routines.. I did not try that approach though.